# Fortran Openmp: Ghost threads interrupt application upon allocate

Tags: fortran, openmp

I am experiencing an issue which starts to drive me crazy. As part of a large software tool I am writing a Fortran module to perform astrodynamic computations.
The main functionality is contained in a subroutine which uses OpenMP and other subroutines to perform its tasks.
The workflow is as follows:

1) Preparations - read in files

2) Start the first parallel omp parallel do

3) Based on the working mode, the function might call itself recursively and process a separate part of the data (thereby executing a second omp do loop)

4) Combine the results into one large array of a derived type

Up to this point everything has been running as expected. Next is the part that fails:

5) Using the results from 4, start another parallel loop to continue the processing.

Step 5 sometimes works and sometimes it stops with an access violation. This is independently of the optimization level selected (nominally we use O2, but it happens also with O0).
Hence I fired up Intel inspector and looked for data races/deadlocs,....

It reported 5 very strange data races, which make no sense to me, as the code locations are either at the definition/end of a subroutine, a codeline reading threadprivate global variable, an Intel MKL routine or at a location reading a local allocatable array which is in a subroutine that is called within the parallel region.
After reading upon things a bit, I enabled the recursive switch to force the local array to end on the stack. Another Inspector analysis was interrupted by the same access violation. When loading the results no errors were detected, but the tool warns that due to the abnormal end data may have been lost.

I then tried to put the entire loop into an OMP critical - just as a test. Now the access violation disappeared, but the code is stuck very early.After processing 15/500 objects it just stops. This looked like a deadlock.
So I continued the search and commented out every OMP statement in the do loop of step 5.
Interestingly the code stops as well at iteration 15!
Hence I used the debugger to locate the call where the infinite waiting state occurs.
It is at the final allocate statement:

```
Subroutine doWork(t0, Pert, allAtmosData, considerArray, perigeeFirstTimeStepUncertainties)
real(dp), intent(in)                                            :: t0                                               
type (tPert), intent(in)                                        :: Pert                                            
type (tThermosphereData), dimension(:), allocatable, intent(in) :: allAtmosData                                                                                                                                                                              
integer(i4), dimension(3), intent(in)                           :: considerArray
real(dp), dimension(:,:), allocatable, intent(out)              :: perigeeFirstTimeStepUncertainties
!Locals:
real(dp), dimension(:), allocatable                     :: solarFluxPerigeeUnc, magneticIndexUnc, modelUnc
integer(i4)                                             :: dataPoints

!Allocate memory for the computations
dataPoints = size(allAtmosData, 1)

allocate(solarFluxPerigeeUnc(0:dataPoints-1), source=0.0_dp)
allocate(magneticIndexUnc(0:dataPoints-1),    source=0.0_dp)
allocate(modelUnc(0:dataPoints-1),            source=0.0_dp)


... Subroutine body ...


!Assign outputs
allocate(perigeeFirstTimeStepUncertainties(3, 0:dataPoints-1), source=0.0_dp)
perigeeFirstTimeStepUncertainties(MGN_SOLAR_FLUX_UNCERTAINTY,:) = solarFluxPerigeeUnc
perigeeFirstTimeStepUncertainties(MGN_MAG_INDEX_UNCERTAINTY,:)  = magneticIndexUnc
perigeeFirstTimeStepUncertainties(MGN_MODEL_UNCERTAINTY,:)      = modelUnc

End Subroutine
```

The subroutine works perfectly in other places of the overall program and also for the first
14 iterations of step 5. In the 15th iteration however it is stuck at the last allocate, or as I just have managed to produce - also results in an access violation.
When I pause the code using the debugger, I see that somehow the openmp library has been loaded and the code hangs/crashes in frontend.cpp, which I have no access to:
[image: Call Stack at error location]

What is happening here? How can a simple allocate suddenly cause and OMP activity in a loop where any OMP statement has been commented out? 
As a sidenote: If I comment out the allocate and pass the size as an extra argument, the same error happens at the next allocate in the code.

Any help or workaround is highly appreciated! I already googled on how to shut down any prior thread-pool, so that there is definately no omp ghost thread activity left, but apparently there is no way to do so. Also ultimately the loop shall work in parallel.

EDIT: I just did a second test on the machine with 2018 v5. It also shows that the allocate statement results in a call to for_alloc_allocatable() and then the OMP statements. Also the mov statement where the program crashes is shown:
[image]

I guess that something is probably causing memory corruption in the second recursive OMP loop, as somehow the allocate is redirected to a threadpool memory allocation, however all threads but the main one should be passive? I cannot read assembler, but I was surprised to find that TBB is used by OpenMp? Could this be a bug in TBB?

Comment: Not a huge amount to go on but a) Have you compiled it (assuming the intel compiler) -check all and run the executable? b) Have you checked it works without OpenMP?

Comment: Hi Ian. Ifort is right. Running Parallel Studio XE 2018 Update 3. The error also happens using Update 5 on anothe machine. I also tried to turn on all runtime checks. No issues were reported. My last hope is currently the memory analysis by Intel inspector. It takes ages (running since 12 hours and is still within the first openmp loop in step 2), but lets see... Currently I am commenting out code and rebuilding, retesting, but nothing concrete comes to mind. Some method to disable openmp entirely after step 4 would be very helpful..

Comment: b) Have you checked it works without OpenMP? i.e. compiling without -qopenmp or whatever the flag is nowadays. Have you tried with gfortran?

Comment: Without openmp everything works properly, but obviously is too slow for actual operations. I did not consider gfortran (as the department requires ifort and also I do not have the rights to install anything on the development machine).

Comment: I just did an edit of the post and added some more info. Can someone who speaks assembler confirm that some sort of memory corruption causes a jump into an invalid memory area which just happens to be some omp code?

Comment: What you are doing is quite complicated - if you can provide a short, complete, compilable, runnable code that shows the same issue it will make it a lot easier for us to help, at the moment I fear it is all but impossible

Comment: Hey Ian. I am aware that it is nearly impossible and that the code is complicated. In fact the problem comes and goes and I only found one specific set of input files and combinations to constantly reproduce it. Interestingly I just found out that it always works if I uncomment the recursive function call of the routine to itself. This is somehow consistent with the fact that uncommenting all OMP codes for the loop where it fails has no effect, as the memory corruption takes place earlier. Are there restrictions with respect to recursive functions containing OMP parallel do loops?

Comment: I have a hinch of what might be happening. I noticed that from time to time a thread in the first parallel loop is modifying its threadprivate global variable (data is dynamically reloaded). This does not lead to issues within the parallel do loop itself, but I guess that extending a threadprivate standard variable is non-defined bahavior. At least I could not find anything about it. But maybe these extensions cause the memory corruption?

Comment: The problem seems to be solved! By making sure that the threadprivate variables are not grown I seem to have gotten rid of the access violations. Hence the question of mine: why is growing a threadprivate variable lead to memory corruption after the parallel region has ended?